# Why MySQL only use composite index but not separate indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

And I need to do following query

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY a, b LIMIT 1;
```

If I add a composite index

```
ALTER TABLE `t_test` ADD INDEX a_b(`a`, `b`);
```

It works

```
> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY a, b LIMIT 1;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | a_b  | 8       | NULL |    1 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

But if I add two index separately

```
ALTER TABLE `t_test` ADD INDEX a(`a`), ADD INDEX b(`b`);
```

It fails

```
> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY a, b LIMIT 1;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Even I add `FORCE INDEX`, it doesn't work.

As my personal understand, it should use both `index a` and `index b` and just a little smaller than composite index.

Even if I'm wrong, it should at least use `index a` first and then use filesort to sort b.

Does this sort operator really can't use separated indexes? If yes, please explain why it doesn't work. If no, do you have any solution to let it work with separate indexes? Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

For example I have 100 lines. I can use `index a` first to sort them. And then in each group with same `a` value, I can use `index b` to sort them.

Why this way can't work on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

When an index (composite or not) is used for "sorting", MySQL reads the data in order, and does no sorting at all. This is not possible with multiple indexes.

Reading in order on the 1-st index and then filesorting is possible, but it's unlikely to be faster, so MySQL doesn't do it.

If you really need to do it, you can use a subquery like this:

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM (
            SELECT primary_key
            FROM table1
            ORDER BY field1
            LIMIT 15
    ) tmp
    JOIN table1 t ON t.primary_key = tmp.primary_key
    ORDER BY field1, field2
```

This can be useful when you have a `LIMIT` and can't add a composite index for some reason.

Comment: Why it's not faster? For example you have (a,b) (3,1), (3,0), (2,1), (2,0), you first need to sort `a` and then `b`. Index on `a` must help the sort. Your query is slow because you do `JOIN`, there is extra cost.

Comment: This query will only be fast if there is a e.g: `LIMIT 20` on 100k rows. MySQL still has to do a "JOIN like operation" to get the data from the primary (clustered) index, which is faster than a explicit JOIN, but still has to happen.

Comment: As I already mentioned there is no such thing as "sorting using an index". The index is an ordered data structure (usually BTREE), which is naturally read in order. If you read two indexes, you then need to combine the result, and then add the other stuff from the clustered index. This will have a higher IO, memory cost, and probably a higher CPU cost compared to just reading the clustered index and sorting.

Comment: So do you mean reading two indexes is slower than one composite index? I totally agree with you. But I think reading two indexes is faster than no index (engine need to sort at runtime, it of course slower than use index), right? If yes, why not mysql use two indexes instead of no index?

Comment: Actually, reading from two indexes and reading a composite (with the same columns) is pretty much the same if you read all the rows (as is the case here). But reading two indexes + merging the data + reading and merging from the primary is likely to be slower than a read from the primary + sorting (for the same reason that my query is slow if you remove the `LIMIT`).

Comment: You still don't get my point. As you said, two indexes and composite index are same. So why MySQL don’t use two indexes, this is my question. And MySQL will ignore sorting in subqury if there is no LIMIT, it's why your query is slow when remove the LIMIT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186861/discussion-between-vatev-and-dean-xu).